# Windows 7 Jump List Displays No Icons

Tags: windows-7, icons, recent-documents, jump-list

The application I'm working on has a set of file types associated with it. Everyone is familiar with Windows 7's new Jump List and its features. If I open a file (double clicking on it or from within my application), my list of 'Recent Documents' in the jump list is populated correctly, but the default 'no icon' is displayed instead of the correct one.

Has anyone ran into this difficulty as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem was simply an installation error. After uninstalling and reinstalling the application, the icons appear with no problems.